# How to reset system idle timer in Windows 11 (SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED) doesn't work)

Tags: winapi, windows-11, power-saving

Earlier, when we call `SetThreadExecutionState(ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)` without `ES_CONTINUOUS`, it reset the system idle timer. But in Windows 11, that doesn't work anymore.

I need the reset the idle timer, and I wonder, how can I do it now?

Comment: Just read the manual carefully. It worked in Windows 10 occasionally. *applications must use both ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED and ES_CONTINUOUS*

Comment: I've done it with ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_CONTINUOUS. But i want to reset timer after i clear flags ( SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS)). Now when i call SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS) pc sleep immediately

Comment: so testing with 1 min display/1 min sleep i've tried keeping the monitor on as well with ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED and that at least seems to work, i disconnect my plex client and after 1 min it turns off both. if i just do ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED it'll sleep immediately. trying just ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED seems to have the same behavior as ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED

Answer (score -2):

According to the Doc:[System Sleep Criteria](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-sleep-criteria)

> To maintain the time since the last user input, the system uses a
> display idle timer and a system idle timer. The system compares the
> idle timers to the values configured in the power plan. If the display
> idle timer value is greater than the display time-out value, and no
> threads have requested the display by calling SetThreadExecutionState
> with ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED, the system powers off the display.
> Similarly, if the system idle timer is greater than the system
> time-out value and no applications have requested the system by
> calling SetThreadExecutionState with ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED, the system
> enters sleep.

When you clear `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED flag`, will allow the system to idle to sleep normally. If the system idle timer is greater than the system time-out value and without ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED flag, the system enters sleep.

Comment: problem is this doesn't seem to reset the timer at all SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED)